# Sqllite exception occur while inserting data from json to query?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, exception

I am trying to add some data from a Json to sqllite TABLE. below my code to download data from json data .and have an external sqllite class for execute my query . dbclass is the object of sqllite class and call a dbclass.setter methode to execute my query

```
     JSONArray item_uom_list = object.getJSONArray("ItemUOM");
                        if (item_uom_list.length() > 0) {
                            dbClass.setterValues("delete from tbl_item_uom");
                            for (int i = 0; i < item_uom_list.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject item_uom_object = item_uom_list.getJSONObject(i);
                                String a = item_uom_object.getString("Org_Id");
                                String b = item_uom_object.getString("Item_No");
                                String c = item_uom_object.getString("Code");
                                String d = item_uom_object.getString("Barcode");
                                String e = item_uom_object.getString("UOMDescription");
                                String f = item_uom_object.getString("UOMQty");
                                String g = item_uom_object.getString("AutoPrice");

                                /*String sql="insert into tbl_item_uom values('?','?','?','?','?','?','?')";
                                dbClass.setterValues(sql,new String[] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g});*/


                                dbClass.setterValues("insert into tbl_item_uom values('" + a + "','" + b + "','" + c + "','" + d + "','" + e + "','" + f + "','" + g + "')");
                            }
                        }
```

And i have external sqllite class ,
my logcat is below

```
                          09-20 14:43:17.670 19871-19871/com.krishna.glowis E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "s": syntax error 09-20 14:43:17.674 19871-19871/com.krishna.glowis D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 09-20 14:43:17.677 19871-19871/com.krishna.glowis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.krishna.glowis, PID: 19871  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into tbl_items values('293','PR111','DIAPER-BE SURE-M 5's','','','','GST@12%','','','1','I','1','','1.0','1.0','10.0','1','411000','131000','449300','511100','442000','N','','1','1','null','Item','2018-08-01 04:33:44.95','N','N') at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1704)
    atandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1635)
    at Support_Classes.DBClass.setterValues(DBClass.java:332)
    at Fragments.Synch_Data$3.onResponse(Synch_Data.java:462)
    at Fragments.Synch_Data$3.onResponse(Synch_Data.java:302)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
```

Comment: someone says u cant able to insert data directly and i dontknow how o insert my data

Comment: Look up Prepared Statements.

Comment: @juergend please share a useful link or solve my problem

Comment: Come on. Just google *Android sqlite prepared statements*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at your log, the very first line tells you your issue. When you try to run your query with value:

```
..., 'DIAPER-BE SURE-M 5's', ...
```

you break the string with apostrophe. use two apostrophes for strings where you need them.

```
..., 'DIAPER-BE SURE-M 5''s', ...
```

Not the double (") apostrophe sign, just two singles (')

Comment: And for the record, stop using a, b, c, d, ... for your variable names, it's a recipe for disaster. Also rather than concatenating strings with ...+ a + '", "' + b... use string formatting at least... It will help a lot ;)

Comment: thank u , but cant able to solved yet       now:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "pen": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: insert into tbl_items values(293,00001,luxy pen,blue lexy,,4365,GST@5,,,1,I,18,,0.225,0.0,1.274,0,411000,131000,449300,511101,442000,N,,2,35,null,Item,2018-08-19 06:42:25.453,'N','N')

Comment: @ShameemAhsan Sry, misread it. you are not using apostrophes on your strings in this case.

Comment: @ Antonio yes am not using apostrophes on my code now .what to do so

Comment: Use them :). You have to use them, you just need to make sure when you have them inside your string that you double them or it will break.

Comment: @ Antonio i cant able to do  apostrophes with this line                                       dbClass.setterValues("insert into tbl_item_uom values('" + a + "','" + b + "','" + c + "','" + d + "','" + e + "','" + f + "','" + g + "')");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180438/discussion-between-shameem-ahsan-and-antonio-sucic).

Answer (score 1):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code
>   1):

```
A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution.
```

You can try with [**`ContentValues`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues).

**DEMO**

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
for (int i = 0; i < item_uom_list.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject item_uom_object = item_uom_list.getJSONObject(i);
    String a = item_uom_object.getString("Org_Id");
    String b = item_uom_object.getString("Item_No");
    String c = item_uom_object.getString("Code");
    String d = item_uom_object.getString("Barcode");
    String e = item_uom_object.getString("UOMDescription");
    String f = item_uom_object.getString("UOMQty");
    String g = item_uom_object.getString("AutoPrice");


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Org_Id", a); 
        values.put("Item_No", b); 
        .......................
        ......................
        values.put("AutoPrice", g); 
        database.insert("tbl_item_uom", null, values);
}

database.close();
```